# how to make downloading info vb.net

Tags: vb.net

how can i make downloading info like what now is downloading

```
label1.text = "Downloading - VisualStudio.exe"
ProgressBar1.Value = 50
My.Computer.Network.DownloadFile("https://URL.com/VisualStudio.exe", "VisualStudio.exe")

label1.text = "Downloading - Visual.exe"
My.Computer.Network.DownloadFile("https://URL.com/VisualStudio.exe", "Visual.exe")
ProgressBar1.Value = 100
label1.text = "Downloaded!"
```

Someting like that

Comment: The DownloadFile method [has an overload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.devices.network.downloadfile?view=windowsdesktop-6.0) that allows you to specify if it should show a progress bar while the download occurs. Just use this overload and you can avoid to implement yourself a progress bar. (By the way, you will never be able to create a progress bar to display updates. DownloadFile has no provision to comunicate with the caller code about its download progression)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be you can achieve simply like this.

Add a dialog to your project. (Add->New Item->Dialog(winforms).

Remove every default created control on dialog.

Add a `Label` and add a `ProgressBar` to the dialog at appropriate places and size.

Initially hide the dialog.

When your business starts, show the dialog as a modal dialog

//Do the business

//Update label and progress bar accordingly

When your business ends, close the dialog.